# update/fix column datatype and records from string to sort by numeric datatype in mysql innoDB database

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, innodb, type-conversion

I need to remove the last character of every record in the column, that is the "€" symbol and convert the data to some numeric type, bear in mind that the data contains dots in it, as in "20.000€" or "1.000€" or "3.200€" as in the example:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/MZcloPx.png]

The idea is to be able to sort the data DESC or ASC, doesn't matter, but it doesnt work now.

What have I tried?

Well I was thinking I could write a python script to do it (i know how) but wondering if there is an easier/faster way to do this...

Thanks!

Comment: If you directly alter the table definition and change column type to a number like int, I think the none numeric is limited by default. But backup your data, I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new column in the table, let's call it newfield then do

UPDATE mytable set newfield = CAST(LEFT(oldfield, length(oldfield)-1))

Then drop the new field.

Comment: haven't tried your solution e4c5, finally i decided to do it with a python script, easier cleaner and faster. thanks anyways, hope this helps someone else tho.